# Bazel iOS Framework

Tags: bazel

I have been unable to find any examples of how to create an iOS framework using Bazel.  There is an `ios_framework` rule, but being new to the build system, I am unsure how to use it.

Is this possible to create a framework, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Have you seen [the tutorial](http://bazel.io/docs/tutorial/index.html), in particular the [iOS app part](http://bazel.io/docs/tutorial/ios-app.html)? It doesn't specifically cover `ios_framework`, but after running through it you should be able understand how to stick a binary and hdrs into and `ios_framework` rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work for you? I've left all of the optionals off to keep things simpler:

BUILD:

```
ios_framework(
    name = "framework",
    binary = ":framework_binary",
)

ios_framework_binary(
    name = "framework_binary",
    srcs = [
        "frameworksource.m",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Sorry, dumb question...but how do I run the build?  Sorry, getting a bit lost in the docs.

Comment: I was just able to run `bazel build //:framework` after doing a `touch WORKSPACE`, though it is returning "xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphonesimulator8.4" cannot be located.", so I'm looking into this next.

Comment: To specify the current SDK version you would use `bazel build //:framework --ios_sdk_version=9.2`